# How to run Windows 7 in docker?

Tags: windows, docker

Can I run a full Windows 7 or 10 on Docker for Windows?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can run Windows with full UI. But we can run core part of it: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/

Answer (score 6):

Docker runs containers. Containers are fundamentally different from a virtual machine. A VM runs an entire operating system. A container is used to run an isolated application with the same host OS kernel. So by definition of the tool, docker cannot run an entire operating system.

Comment: while i get your logic but i am no expert so don't know how much this https://github.com/sickcodes/Docker-OSX is opposite to what you said.

Comment: @user734028 in that scenario, they're escaping the container by mounting /dev/kvm so they can ask the Linux host to run a VM.

Answer (score 5):

I am not aware of any fully dockerized Windows 7 OS.

You can acheive that in an indirect way. You can start virualbox inside a container and run Windows7 from there. Check the following [Dockerfile](https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/blob/master/virtualbox/Dockerfile) to start virtualbox inside a container (Instructions are in the comments)

Comment: Thanks, yamenk. But docker container starts fast, while vm does not. If start VB in container then start VM, that is not cool... : (

Comment: windows 7 docker image ; https://hub.docker.com/r/surazzarus/windows7-starter